# How to get AES key from java code so that i can save it in a text file?

Tags: java, cryptography, aes, encryption-symmetric

I have tried below code to get AES key from java code. And the output is also captured after the code.

```
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
     KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGenerator.init(256);
      System.out.println("key algo: " + keyGenerator.generateKey().getAlgorithm());
      System.out.println("key format: " + keyGenerator.generateKey().getFormat());
      System.out.println("key generated: " + keyGenerator.generateKey());  // this seems to be equivallent to keyGenerator.generateKey().toString()
      System.out.println("key (getEncoded): " + keyGenerator.generateKey().getEncoded());
    }
}
```

Output:   I see below output for above code.

```
key algo: AES   
key format: RAW   
key generated: javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@fffe8a11   
key (getEncoded): [B@26653222
```

I am not sure if `keyGenerator.generateKey().getEncoded()` result is what i need to use as a key that can be saved in a text file and used between application.

**Can someone Answer.** What I want is to save the AES key in a text file and send it over through email or some secure means. So the other application can use this key to decrypt the messages.

Comment: An AES key is simply a random byte sequence that is 16, 24 or 32 bytes long. `keyGenerator.generateKey().getEncoded()` returns this byte sequence (32 bytes in your case, since you initialized the `KeyGenerator` instance that way). To store this as text, a binary-to-text encoding like Base64 or hex encoding has to be used.

Comment: @Topaco -  `System.out.println("key (size in bytes): " + keyGenerator.generateKey().getEncoded().toString().getBytes().length);
`  output `11`. Am i missing something. If you wish you could turn your comments in to an answer.

Comment: @Topaco - this thing worked `System.out.println("key (length): " + keyGenerator.generateKey().getEncoded().length);` output - `32`

Comment: Please find a full example for AES-CBC enryption using a Base64-encoded key here (Disclaimer: I'm the author): https://github.com/java-crypto/cross_platform_crypto/blob/main/AesCbc256StringEncryption/AesCbc256StringEncryption.java

Answer (score 1):

you can encode the bytes to Base64 string like this:

```
SecretKey key = keyGenerator.generateKey();
Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(key.getEncoded())
```